# tvOS Simulator Build - Installation Failed

Tags: xcode, tvos, xcode7.1

When building an application for the Apple tvOS simulator using Xcode 7.1, upon the deployment phase, Xcode throws the following error and fails to deploy the application to the simulator.

**Installation Failed**

*Invalid argument*

[image: installation failed]

Any ideas what could be wrong? I had a look on the Apple Developer forums and some people talked about reading a resources folder incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Make sure you have a bundle identifier for the app set. It just cannot be empty when deploying to a device or simulator.

In the project I was creating above I had not set a bundle identifier for the app and so it was failing from that. If you have a bundle identifier and are still getting this error, check the other critical info.

Comment: is there other work around for this issue? I am still getting issue